# Toggle "RNPickerSelect" on "onPress" not working

Tags: react-native, dropdown, react-native-cli

So I've been looking for a dropdown picker to be toggled on "on Press" since yesterday yet I found nothing, all I want is to put an icon in a "touchable Opacity", and when pressed the dropdown picker shows.
I've been advised to use "react-native-picker-select" library, I imported it and added the usage advised by the library like this

```
const Dropdown = () => {
     return (
         <RNPickerSelect
             onValueChange={(value) => console.log(value)}
             items={[
                 { label: 'Football', value: 'football' },
                 { label: 'Baseball', value: 'baseball' },
                 { label: 'Hockey', value: 'hockey' },
             ]}
         />
     ); };
```

then I called it from the "on Press" but its showing nothing, so what am I missing?

Comment: Where's your onPress and what do you mean by 'nothing showing' ?

Comment: "onPress={() => Dropdown()}" here is my onPress, and i mean that it gives no errors but the dropdown doesnt show at all

Comment: that doesnt work like that, are you trying to open the drop down when clicking a touchable opacity ?

Comment: yes thats exactly what i want

Comment: You should use something like a ref to do that, but couldnt find a way in the docs of rnpicker

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to call whole element on pressing the button, but there is no need to do that because react-native-picker-select by default supports on press focus which you want. While native 'Picker' from 'react-native' does not support that.

So, you can add this directly like a View or TouchableOpacity.
For example:

```
const App = () => {
    return (
         <View />
         <RNPickerSelect />
         ...
    );
}
```

Comment: what i want is to set a custom icon to toggle the drop down when pressed, what the library offers is like a text box that toggles it when pressed

Comment: Do you want this for android or iOS?

Comment: i want it for android